# Sci-fi book series about an ex-soldier who's kidnapped from Earth by a spaceship-stealing robot, and goes on to create a mercenary band

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

A series of multiple books (recent; still writing more in the series). An ex-soldier living in their parents' cabin stumbles on a damaged spaceship in the woods, is kidnapped by the robot captain (who himself stole the ship) and taken to a slavehold, where the ex-soldier frees several other creatures and a robot (later named Lucky). They steal the ship from the first robot and become mercenaries, get lots of jobs, and eventually have to save the Earth from the original robot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please split this into two separate questions, so they can each be answered.

Comment: @Varikk - I've edited your question to focus on the book series only, as story-ID questions should only ask about a single work or series of works. If you still want the other book identified, please do go ahead and post that as a separate question. You can copy your description of the other book from the [revision history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/259654/revisions) of this question.

Comment: @LogicDictates I think you are taking a bit too much liberty here in service of your answer.  Yes, we're all impatient to answer questions, but I think rewriting the question to fit your answer goes a bit too far.

Comment: @DavidW - _"Rewriting the question to fit [my] answer"_ is a rather loaded way to put it. The edits I performed did two things: 1) removed the description of the second work, for which no answer has yet been submitted, and 2) improved the grammar in the description of the first work. I didn't fundamentally alter the meaning of anything that was written, and aside from removing the description of the second work, it was a standard, run-of-the-mill edit like dozens of similar edits I've performed in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The first series might be the ***[Omega Force](https://www.goodreads.com/series/113707-omega-force)*** series by Joshua Dalzelle. There are currently thirteen books in the series, with the first book having been published in 2013, and the most recent in 2020.

Here's the Goodreads synopsis for the first book, *[Omega Rising](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17413290-omega-rising)* (2013).

> **Jason Burke was a man hiding from himself in a small cabin high in the American Rocky Mountains** when his simple, quiet life was shattered one night by what he first assumed was an aviation mishap. But when he investigates the crash, what he finds will yank him out of his self-imposed exile and thrust him into a world he could have never imagined.
>
> **He suddenly finds himself trapped on a damaged alien spacecraft and plunged into a universe of interstellar crime lords and government conspiracies, along the way meeting strange new friends… and enemies.** As he struggles to find his way back home he is inexorably drawn deeper into a world where one misstep could mean his death. Or worse. He desperately wants to get back to Earth, but it may be the end for him.
>
> … or is it just the beginning?

[This review](https://swlothian.com/2015/12/09/book-review-omega-rising-omega-force-1-joshua-dalzelle/) mentions "a lone synth named, Deetz, who runs the ship" (i.e. a robot captain).

> **Omega Rising is an interesting account of a guy, Jason Burke, who has moved away from the big city (and his problems) to a solitary existence of an isolated cabin.** It’s not the setting you would expect when you pick up a science fiction book. **It’s not long before he sets off to investigate an unexpected event, and stumbles aboard an alien spacecraft. His life takes a major turn as the cargo bay doors close and he finds himself trapped and then launched into the depths of space.** It’s an adventure that he had no choice but to accept.
>
> **Jason soon meets a lone synth named, Deetz, who runs the ship.** He’s a mysterious fellow who quickly accepts his new stowaway (or is he a captive?), after recognizing there was potential to gain benefit from him. The plot is a switch on the standard – who is the alien question. Normally it’s those other than human who are alien, but in this book, Jason the human is the alien.
>
> After agreeing to help Deetz with a ‘job’ in exchange for being returned to Earth, they head to the far reaches of space. Things are going well until they’re attacked when collecting a mystery cargo from a distant planet. In the process, another alien is wounded and saved by Jason, and ultimately ends up onboard the ship just before they escape.
>
> Just imagine being thrown into something completely different to your normal environment. You’d need to learn how to use and react to everything you come into contact with. Dalzelle has covered that off with some clever ways to get past the communication barrier, and there’s a rather ingenious method of giving Jason the skills required to function in his new environment. Tick.
>
> With an escape under their belt and bonding underway, Deetz still has some debts to settle, so they take on a mission to deliver a cargo to a place called The Vault. It’s a place where things can get very dangerous. Jason and his new alien buds soon discover that not all friends are really friends. There’s an overthrow, then there’s a plan, which leads to another plan etc. (Trying not to reveal too much here).
>
> We are hit with some teasers about something that spells doom for the future, and there’s promise of plenty of dramas for the crew to solve. It’s enough to spark interest for readers to jump on-board for future instalments of the series.
>
> This first Omega book is an origins story of how a bunch of random beings are brought together. With their initial mission completed, they realise that they all have a common past and a common goal for the future. So… Omega Force is born.

[This reader review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1620439570?book_show_action=true&from_review_page=1) mentions a synthetic warrior dubbed 'Lucky 7', and states that the protagonist had recently served in Afghanistan.

> **Jason Burke is an American, age 26, who recently served in Afghanistan.** When a damaged spaceship lands near his lonely cabin in the Rocky Mountains, he offers help. Next thing we know, he's Commander Burke, leading a crew of five benign aliens (including an artificial intelligence /Battle Synthetic) across galaxies on a quest to free slaves and put a stop to illegal genetics manipulation.
>
> Feels like Firefly, but not so sophisticated, and there are no female crew members and so far, no special abilities.
> Feels like Guardians of the Galaxy, but there is no cassette recording of best hits.
>
> Main Characters:
>
> Commander Jason Burke.
>
> Blue skinned engineer / mechanic Twingo
>
> Doctor Jorven Ma'Fredich (Doc)
>
> A 4-armed computer hacker, code slicer named Cage
>
> Wolf-man warrior named Crusher
>
> An AI, **a fully armed Battle Synthetic warrior dubbed Lucky 7.**
>
> A synthetic named Deetz
>
> A slave-trading snake-man mobster named Bondrass.

Comment: @Varikk - If you want someone to identify the second book, you'll need to post a separate question for that one, as we don't ID multiple books within a thread here.